# aes encrypt when app in background takes too long swift

Tags: ios, swift, aes, background-process

I am having a problem when trying to encrypt data when the app is in background, the same function works properly when the app is in foreground

```
func crypt(dados: String, sistema: String) -> String {
        let key = "ie2kiei2-\(sistema)"
        let key_p = key.leftPadding(toLength: 32, withPad: "0")
        
        do {
            let aes = try AES(key: key_p, iv: "12493274392")
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            semaphore.signal()
            let ciphertext = try aes.encrypt(Array(dados.utf8))
            semaphore.wait()
            let data = NSData(bytes: ciphertext, length: ciphertext.count)
            return data.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return "erro"
    }
```

When i start encrypting the data, it takes too long and didnt finish when gets to this line

`let ciphertext = try aes.encrypt(Array(dados.utf8))`

After i open the app again and it cames to foreground, it continues the code and finalize the task.

What could be happen on this line to this happen?

Comment: How large is your data sample?

Comment: What is your background mode trigger?  How do you call this function from that trigger?

Comment: @soundflix is it 107124 bytes

Comment: @Paulw11 i am using BGTaskScheduler and it calls a function to gather the data to crypt

Comment: Is it a BGAppRefreshTask or a BGProcessingTask?  They have different limits in when they will execute and how much processing time and power they have access to.

Comment: @Paulw11 i didnt know that, i am using BGProcessingTask, the whole process dont pass 10 seconds of processing

Comment: The important point with a BGprocessingTask is that if the user picks up their device and starts using it then your task will be terminated. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask

Comment: You may also need to consider the data protection that is applied to the data you need; if data or a key that you require isn't available when the device is locked, you may have a problem. It is odd that you say that the processing continues when the app returns to the foreground. That isn't how bgprocessingtasks work. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to show more detail on how you schedule and invoke your task and function